# Rambam on writing Teffilin and Mezuzah on Chol Hamoed

Tags: halacha, rambam, tefilin, mezuzah, chol-hamoed

The Rambam in Hilchot Yom Tov (7,13) says that on Hol Hamoed it is Assur to write Tefilin or Mezuzah for others unless the Sofer needs the money for Tzorech Yom-Tov. Kesef Mishneh says that the Rambam does not count the writing of the Tefilin itself as a Tzorech Yom-Tov, because the Rambam holds that one does not put on Tefillin during Hol Hamoed. But Mezuzah surely is something that is needed on Hol Hamoed for someone who doesn't have a mezuzah!

Why isn't writing a Mezuzah for others a Tzorech of the Moed?

Comment: Seems more like a question on the Kesef Mishne than the Rambam. The simple answer is just the Rambam thought Tefillin should be worn on chol hamoed

Comment: @DoubleAA Rambam differs from Rashi’s understanding of the Gemara (MK 19a); Rashi learns that כדי פרנסתו does not mean אין לו מה יאכל. From the fact that he doesn’t learn like Rashi, but rather learns that כדי פרנסתו does indeed mean אין לו מה יאכל, it would seem to indicate that he *must* fall back on that, that he doesn’t have an alternative reason (i.e. wearing tefillin on Chol HaMoed) to justify it as a צורך המועד. Thus, the Kesef Mishneh infers that the Rambam does not hold that we wear tefillin on Chol HaMoed. He pretty much spells this out in Beis Yosef OC 545.

Comment: @user17880 ^^^ If you want to edit in these sources, it might help to strengthen your question a bit.

Comment: @Doniel again all very consistently a problem for the Kesef Mishneh

Comment: @DoubleAA What I mean to say is that based on the Rambam itself, the Kesef Mishnah’s approach is very logical. How else can you explain the Rambam? That Tefillin *should* be worn on Chol HaMoed? Then why did he not explain like Rashi?

Comment: @Doniel because needing extra money for meat on yom tov isn't a reason to permit melakha (or whatever you'll have to anyway say about mezuza, as the OP points out)

Comment: Note that Kessef Mishneh makes the opposite inference (i.e. according to Rambam one does wear tefillin on chol hamoed) in [Hilchot Tefillin 4:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.4.10.1?lang=bi)

Comment: @DoubleAA If you needed tefillin on the Moed then it would be a tzorech in and of itself. It wouldn’t matter how much you’re selling it for.

Comment: @Doniel I don't see what you're adding

Comment: @DoubleAA If Tefillin is inherently a tzorech HaMoed, then one should be allowed to write tefillin even for others and even for a profit. From the fact that the Rambam requires that the sofer need the proceeds for Yom Tov, it implies that Tefillin is not inherently a tzorech HaMoed, as if they were, he wouldn’t have needed a different heter.

Comment: @Doniel Rashi also requires the proceeds be for moed. It's just a matter of degree: basic moed needs vs expanded Simchat Yom Tov.

Comment: @DoubleAA Where does Rashi say that? I see the Beis Yosef cites other Poskim which say it’s for Simchas Yom Tov, with the nafka minah being a rich person, but he never says that that is Rashi’s opinion.

Comment: @Doniel How would Rashi explain what כדי פרנסתו means in the Mishnah?

Comment: @DoubleAA How do you learn that the Rambam rules tefillin should be worn on chol hamoed? Unless you mean the kessef mishne understood the Rambam that way...which would be a kushya on the KM.

Comment: @JoelK Rashi holds that one does put on Tefillin, therefore he doesn’t need to fall back on אין לו מה יאכל. Beis Yosef that I cited earlier makes this point explicitly (though he says it regarding the Rosh, who learns the Braisa the same as Rashi).

Comment: @Doniel The mishnah says you can write tefillin for yourself, but not for others, unless it’s כדי פרנסתו. Even if one holds that tefillin are laid on chol hamoed, there is a distinction between when one is allowed to write for oneself and when one is allowed to write for others

Comment: @JoelK Rashi to the Mishnah addresses that, where he says that one may write tefillin for himself “to perform the mitzvah,” but for the community - even for the mitzvah - to sell would be considered melacha b’moed. R’ Yosi in the Braisa disagrees on this latter point, and we pasken like R’ Yosi.

Answer (score 1):

[R. Shlomo Kluger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Kluger) in Binyan Shlomo (printed in the back of many editions of Rambam, and quoted by the Sefer HaLikuttim in the back of the Fraenkel edition Rambam) suggests two answers:

1. *Mezuzah* is never a *tzorech hamoed* - one can gift one’s house to another and thus become exempt from having to place a *mezuzah* there.
2. *Mezuzah* is not a *mitzvah* incumbent on one’s body. As such, if one is prevented from putting one up due to the prohibition against *melachah*, it’s as if he has fulfilled the *mitzvah* regardless. Writing a *mezuzah* is therefore not a *tzorech hamoed*. *Tefillin*, however, are incumbent on the body. If one was obligated to lay *tefillin* on *chol hamoed*, then being prevented from doing so due to the *melachah* involved would not make it as if he had fulfilled the *mitzvah*. So writing them would be a *tzorech hamoed*.

Comment: Gifting your house just makes it a Davar Haaveid which is an even stronger reason to do work than Tzorekh HaMoed.

Comment: Is there any other precedent for treating oneis as stricter for mitzvot shebegufo? The whole line of thought reminds me of the discussion about wearing an invalid tallit on Shabbat when you can't tie the strings to fix it.